# Setting the Width for my Photo Gallery

Tags: html, css

I have tried divs and tables but nothing is working to set the width for the photo gallery. I want the navigation links to be more narrow so that it's not scrollable any more in the browser. The source code is at http://madmediaonline.digimedia2.net/test/

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you question is. At a high level view, your slider seems to be set to 700px. What are you trying to achieve?